# Appium driver cannot find any elements in the UI of the app. Tried find element by id,xpath,name.Nothing seems to work

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation, appium, appium-android

This is my Eclipse test code

---

```
package com.example;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionId;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class FirstAppiumTest {
    //protected AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = null;
    public AppiumDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    public void Setup() throws MalformedURLException
    {String url = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";

        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();

    cap.setCapability("noReset","true");
    cap.setCapability("deviceName","Redmi 4");
    cap.setCapability("platformVersion","7.1.2");
    cap.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    cap.setCapability("app","C:\\Appium\\selendroid-test-app.apk");



     driver=new AndroidDriver(new URL(url),cap);
    }
    @Test
    public void Simpletest() throws InterruptedException
    {  
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.Button")).click();
        WebElement e1=driver.findElement(By.id("showToastButton"));
        e1.click();
         System.out.print(e1);
 String text=driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).getText();
     System.out.print(text);
     String src = driver.getPageSource();
       System.out.println(src);         
      driver.quit();


    }
}
```

---

Here when i try to print e1 it shows me the object value.But when i try to click or getText it shows an exception.Also driver.quit and driver.getPageSource() seems to work.
The log in the console is as follows

---

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
>   Apr 27, 2018 11:16:16 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   FAILED: Simpletest
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
>       at com.example.FirstAppiumTest.Simpletest(FirstAppiumTest.java:56)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

===============================================

Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Comment: Seems half of your code is commented out. Can you update the question with the relevant lines of code?

Comment: All these commented codes were tried and didnt work.

Comment: please check the newly edited code.

Comment: Did you notice that while you updated your working code your question related to `try to print e1` and `click or getText` have become invalid?

Comment: Can you please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

First change @BeforeTest to @BeforeMethod cause your as running the test class it self and not running by xml runner. please pay attention to the differences between  the annotations types.

Is the driver created and the app gas been opened in the device? if so try to use android element instead of webelement.
If above didn't work and the driver is not null please try clicking on the element using android ui automator selector.

Comment: The app can be opened in the device.The elements can be clicked from the appium inspector and the device responds correspondingly.

Comment: When i try to change WebElement to AndroidElement the following error occurs "cannot convert from capture#3-of ? to AndroidElement"

Comment: Can you share the ui inspector page with the elements?

Comment: Did you mean the appium server log page.? Iam not using ui inspector.

Comment: How do you locate the elements? How do you know that the specific element you need has X id or name ...?

Comment: I have an inspector within the appium server.

Comment: Share the inspector page which points to the problematic element as screenshot.

Comment: I could not find a solution to this problem.Instead i found another way to run my test project.I created a maven project and included all my dependencies in the pom.xml file thus the maven imported all my needed dependencies and the project did run successfully without any errors.I think there was some error in adding the dependency files in the previous case.The pom.xml file i used:https://notepad.pw/AppiumTest

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem now?
And did you try running on different device? Try to change no reset to false and see the Appium server log in case of failure. Don't forget to share more info.

Comment: No i was able to run the test case but not in the usual way of adding dependency jar into referenced library list manually.Instead i used the maven project to build my test project.

Comment: That's great, maven is important for you in the future.
Try to read about maven's goals and how to add parameters and about parallelism. 
Good luck and I think now you can accept my answer.